# How to install elementary's Pantheon Photos on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, elementary, image-viewers, pantheon

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with GNOME 3.36 with the X11 window system. I want to install the elementary OS's Photos app (Pantheon Photos). I don't need anything else. I am happy with GNOME and I'm not trying to install Pantheon or elementary at all.

Note: I am not a power user but a beginner in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the Elementary Photos application using its [source code](https://github.com/elementary/photos). First, clone the package using `git` and `cd` to the cloned directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/elementary/photos.git
cd photos
```

Then follow the steps provided by the [Package Maintainer in the project's README](https://github.com/elementary/photos/blob/master/README.md):

> ### Building, Testing, and Installation
>
> You'll need the following dependencies:
>
> - desktop-file-utils
> - intltool
> - libaccounts-glib-dev
> - libexif-dev
> - libgee-0.8-dev
> - libgeocode-glib-dev
> - libgexiv2-dev
> - libglib2.0-dev
> - libgphoto2-dev
> - libgranite-dev >= 6.0.0
> - libgstreamer1.0-dev
> - libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
> - libgtk-3-dev
> - libgudev-1.0-dev
> - libhandy-1-dev
> - libjson-glib-dev
> - libraw-dev
> - librest-dev
> - libsignon-glib-dev
> - libsoup2.4-dev
> - libsqlite3-dev
> - libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev
> - libwebp-dev
> - libxml2
> - meson
> - valac >= 0.40
>
> Run
>
> ```
> ls 
> cd photos/
> ```
>
> Run `meson build` to configure the build environment. Change
> to the build directory and run `ninja` to build
>
> ```
> meson build --prefix=/usr
> cd build
> ninja
> ```
>
> To install, use `ninja install`, then execute with `io.elementary.photos`
>
> ```
> sudo ninja install
> io.elementary.photos
> ```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what is meson build --prefix=/usr   ?? is usr my username?

Comment: I didnt like elementary. just need photos app. I just didn't understand what I need to write as the directory. I don't know where the git files are? I completed git clone command but tucked afterwards

Comment: @tolsnel In the `meson build --prefix=/usr` command, `/usr` is the directory, not your username, so you should just run the command as is. In general, `--prefix=/path/to/dir` is used to specify where the package is going to be installed. In the case of `--prefix=/usr`, the package will be installed in your `/usr` directory.